# Javascript to open a modal in while loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have created a modal which shows up when a `<div>` is clicked but its working for only 1st result of while loop. I think I must assign a unique ID for the same. I tried but this one is not in jquery but javascript. So I am a confused on how to do it.

Javascript:

```
var modal = document.getElementById('edit-post-model-box');
var btn = document.getElementById("edit-post-model");
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<?php while($get_stf = $abc->fetch()) { ?>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" id="edit-post-model" data-row="<?php echo $get_stf['sts_id']; ?>" class="edit-status-post">Edit Post</a></li>
        <li class="border-bottom-none"><a href="">Delete Post</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="edit-post-model-box" class="modal" data-row="<?php echo $get_stf['sts_id']; ?>">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <span class="close">x</span>
            <p><?php echo $get_stf['sts_id']; ?></p>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

The model currently works with only on the 1st result in while loop. Please help me use `<?php echo $get_stf['sts_id']; ?>` as a unique ID in a relevent way so that it works on all results. I have used `data-row` as an attribute to assign unique IDs. Please help he fix the Javascript with the unique IDs.

Comment: In document could be only one element with unique id, use class instead, `getElementById` return only one element, guess this is the problem... also u select all `close` spans with `getElementsByClassName` but then you select only first by `[0]`

Answer (score 0):

You should use the id attribute to manage unique IDs in Javascript:

```
<?php for($i=0;$i<3;$i++){  ?>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#" id="edit-post-model_<?php echo $i; ?>" class="edit-status-post">Edit Post</a></li>
    <li class="border-bottom-none"><a href="">Delete Post</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="edit-post-model-box_<?php echo $i; ?>" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <span id="close_<?php echo $i; ?>">x</span>
        <p><?php echo $i; ?></p>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    document.getElementById("edit-post-model_<?php echo $i; ?>").onclick = function() {
        document.getElementById('edit-post-model-box_<?php echo $i; ?>').style.display = "block";
    };

    document.getElementById("close_<?php echo $i; ?>").onclick = function() {
        document.getElementById('edit-post-model-box_<?php echo $i; ?>').style.display = "none";
    };
</script>
<?php } ?>
```